# How can I proof that a textbody contains my text excerpt

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hello I want to write a program that refreshes the site until my text excerpt isn´t contain my text anymore.
What is my failure?

```
from selenium 
import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://...')
time.sleep(8)
text = driver.find_elements_by_id('lbHeaderP')

time.sleep(8)
while "My text excerpt" in text:

    driver.navigate().refresh()

else:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: You never update `text`. Move `text = ...` into your loop. You probably want to move your sleep in there, too.

Comment: that still won't work.  find_elements will return an array of webelement references.  You need to iterate and call .text() method on each element.  (or get innerHTML attribute depending on your needs)  Though not sure why you'd use find_elements on a webelement with an ID.  (an element with an ID attribute should be unique, so there'd be only 1)

Comment: selenium has two similar functions: `find_elements_by_id` (with char `s` in word `elements`) to find all elements and get it as list (even if there is only one element or if there is no elements) and it need to use `text[0].text()` to get text from first element. And `find_element_by_id` (without char `s` in word `elements`) which gets first element (Or raise error) and it also need `text.text()` to get text. But in both situations you have to run this `find_...` inside `while`-loop.

Comment: Are there multiple elements you are finding with that selector? Since `find_elements_by_id` returns an array of webelements the condition `"my text excerpt" in text"` will never be satisfied.

Comment: I have edit my code and now it is working: `import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://...')
text = driver.find_element_by_id('lbHeaderP').text
time.sleep(8)

while "my text excerpt" in text:
    driver.get('https://...')
    time.sleep(2)
    
else:
    driver.quit()